# In Sphinx, can I prevent the list format from changing when including a .. note:: within the list?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

```
#. List number one
#. Part two

   .. note:: adding some note

#. part three
```

Doing the above causes the spacing or format, in the numbered list to change when compared to a numbered list without a note.  For clarity, the text becomes this:

```
1. List number one


2. List number two


NOTE


3. Part three
```

Rather than doing this:

```
1. List number one
2. Part Two
NOTE
3. Part three
```

Is this a problem with Sphinx, or is it a theme issue?

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace has meaning in reStructuredText.  Directives within a bulleted list require blank lines around them, similar to [nested lists](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bullet-lists).

```
#. List number one
#. Part two

   .. note:: adding some note

#. part three
```

Comment: This is actually how it's written as per your suggestion, and an extra carriage return is adding in the HTML page.

Comment: There is a known issue in [docutils](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2258). Examine the generated HTML output. Then you can apply a custom style to your theme to remove the extra margin for `<p>` within `<li>`.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'll check this, though for all the trouble this is causing I think I'll leave the note outside the numbered list!